# Can you use something like the WHERE clause after you did your query?

Tags: php, sql

So i end up with lots and lots of queries.
Im wondering if you can just run 1 query to get all the info you require for said page.

And then later use php to more or less split the query into different once like if you where to use the WHERE clause in SQL.

My case

I want to get the number of rows for 2 different tasks but from the same table.
1 being where the id is filtered and the other where lets say the user is filtered.

How i typically do it is just make 2 queries and use the where clause to so define the 2.
It just seems rather inefficient to me to make more queries while they all come from the same table.

If there is a way to achieve this that would be awesome to know, I did some tries my self but thus far failed to succeed.
Fiddled around with multidimensional arrays.

Example

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE type = 'type7' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$var = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE type = 'type2' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$var1 = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE type = 'type5' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$var2 = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Since its going to be taken from the same table anyways why have multiple queries just to filter it?

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: Its more in general, Im just wondering if you could still filter the queries after you fetched them, WIthout the need to create more queries wich would more or less do the same thing with a minor change.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question and the most basic answer is not language-specific, i.e. it's true of PHP, Java, and other languages.

Imagine you have a page that displays all banking transactions. You would have a SQL statement along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions
```

If you then wanted to display only a subset of these, you could simply use code (PHP/Java) to filter them and display the result. For instance, in Java you would use lists to store the entire data and streams to filter the ones you want to show. In PHP, you would use [array maps](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

But your approach has issues: you are going to be selecting a lot more data than need be (most likely). This won't perform well and you will hit UX issues such as pagination.

Answer (score 1):

You **can** query everything at once and then filter with php using foreach. But I'd guess that is slower then the 2 queries.

Having two queries is not inefficient. Actually it is using the (usually very fast Database) how it is intended to.

If speed is a factor you could always combine your queries into one using subselects.

```
 SELECT ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE name LIKE 'john%'), ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE id < 3)
```

Alternatively you could set up a (slow) view or have a database [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) that updates the counts in a type of caching table.

Honestly this is probably the wrong place to optimise.

Comment: Not so much the speed, More regarding lines of code, Often times i find my self needing multiple queries from the same table in order to split them up.

Comment: If it is about readability then I'd leave the queries as they are now and have a nicely named method (in my repository) to call them. It really kind of depends. I mean if you have a 200 line sql statement no one can understand anymore, than it maybe is the right call to pull it into PHP. That's a big maybe.

Comment: Well lets say you have a foreach loop.
You require the id it puts out on the next cycle.
For a query to select something specific from the database. I usually put a query inside the loop, It doesnt look pretty especially when you are doing it within HTML code.

So it makes sense to me to get all the data before hand,  With joins and then just have a if to check only fetch the thing you need where its id coresponds with it.

Its kinda hard to explain.

Comment: I can't say I understood all of that... So you have a query in a loop? It really depends on the whole picture. Do you only need the counts? Do you need the objects? How often do you need it? How often does the data change? A trigger updating all counts and then querying that data at once would be a good idea, if you needed the data regularly and fast, but that adds complexity. If you need the objects than prefetching them (like you suggested) would reduce hydration cost, but only works for small databases. It seems to boils down to readability. That is something you have to decide for yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one query.  Something like this:

```
select count(*) as total,
       sum( <filtering conditions here> ) as filtered_total
from t;
```

MySQL treats boolean values as numbers with `0` for false and `1` for true, so the `sum()` counts the number of true values.

Comment: Wouldnt this also lead into 2 queries if you want to count for diffrent filters?

Comment: @Frontliner . . . No.  This is one query.

Comment: Sorry i meant SQL code lines.

Answer (score 0):

you can use UNION or UNION ALL

for example

```
SELECT userName, mail
FROM user
WHERE mail like '%gmail.com%'

UNION ALL

SELECT userName, mail
FROM user
WHERE userName like '%john%'
```

to remove duplicates use only UNION

Comment: Yea this is somewhat the aproach i take, My issue is that you will have 2 queries.
In this case what i want to achieve here is to have 1 query that sellects all from users.

Once you fetched all of that, You can then filter it trough PHP